# ISNULL returning truncated string

Tags: sql-server

I'm having an unusual issue:

```
DECLARE @enabledClients TABLE(id int); --Some clients will have this setting enabled by default
DECLARE @enabled nvarchar(10);

INSERT INTO @enabledClients (id) SELECT [id] FROM dbo.client WHERE name IN ('FOO', 'BAR');
```

As I loop through each client, I want to set `@enabled` to true or false:

```
WHILE @clientId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @enabled = ISNULL((SELECT 'true' from @enabledClients where id = @clientId), 'false');
     ...
    SET @clientId = (SELECT MIN(clientId) FROM dbo.client WHERE id > @clientId);
END
```

If the client is 'FOO' or 'BAR', `@enabled` is 'true' as expected. If not, `@enabled` is 'fals'. Not 'false', which I expect, but the 4-character string 'fals'. Why would that be?

Comment: Also the "looping through" should probably be avoided in favour of a set based solution.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'd welcome your input, I'll post another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ISNULL` returns a result with the datatype of the first parameter. The string literal 'true' is treated as `varchar(4)`

You can use `coalesce` to get the desired result but that [will execute the query twice](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery).

You can stick with `isnull` and cast the literal in the first query to `varchar(5)` to avoid this issue.

`cast('true' as varchar(5))`

Comment: COALESCE also returns the datatype of the first non-null value.

Comment: @SeanLange `COALESCE` returns the data type according to: *Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable.*

Comment: @SeanLange `coalesce` is equivalent to `case` and uses datatype precedence rules.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the same thing after a long time researching why a complex query that included ISNULL()'s was sometimes failing.  **ISNULL() is apparently dangerous to use with character data whenever what follows the comma evaluates to a length greater than one!**  If what follows the comma evaluates to more than one character, then the programmer must be careful that it evaluates to no larger than the size of what proceeds the comma.  My prior understanding of ISNULL was that whatever is after the comma will replaces whatever is before the comma, if what is before the comma evaluates to NULL.  But that turns out to be wrong.  It turns out that whatever is after the comma will be cast into the format of whatever is before the comma, then replaces the NULL value.  I wrote a query that demonstrates this well:

```
/* 
With commented line left out, result is "54321"
Uncommenting the line produces "12345" NOT "1234567890"
*/

DECLARE @First VARCHAR(5) = '54321'
DECLARE @Second VARCHAR(10) = '1234567890'

--SET @First = NULL

SELECT ISNULL(@First, @Second)
```